# Can web application run on Apache web server?

Tags: apache, tomcat

Can we run web application containing jsp servlets on Apache server?

Or do we need to integrate with tomcat?

I have researched and there are ways to run jsp servlets on apache but what i want to know is which one performs well : 
**1. Only on Apache?
2. Integrate tomcat with apache?**

Comment: Can you please elaborate on 'there are ways to run jsp servlets on apache' ?

Comment: Apache is the name of a big software company with many products such as Apache HTTPD and Apache Tomcat. Your question is therefore very confusing. Don't you actually mean the product "Apache HTTPD"? when you said "Apache" without any additives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @BalusC mentioned, I guess you mean "Apache Tomcat" (which is a Java application server) and the "Apache HTTPD" (wich is a web server).

Basically you can not use the "Apache HTTPD" with JSPs since they need to be compiled by a JSP compiler. That JSP compiler is part of the "Apache Tomcat" (or any other Java application server like Jetty).